# Python: Concatenate string separated by comma in pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

After using a TextBlob spell corrector, the sentence in each row becomes separated by comma.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
list = df['sentence'].tolist()

def TBSpellCorrector(sentence):
    b = TextBlob(sentence)
    return b.correct()

df['corrected_sentence']=df['sentence'].apply(TBSpellCorrector)
```

Result:

```
    sentence         corrected_sentence
132 on fre     (o, n,, f, i, r, e)             
35  beautful    (b, e, a, u, t, i, f, u, l)
```

I need to concatenate the sentence separated by comma.

```
Expected Output
    sentence         corrected_sentence        corrected_sentence2
132 on fre           (o, n,, f, i, r, e)             on fire
35  beautful    (b, e, a, u, t, i, f, u, l)         beautiful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.correct()` method returns a *`textblob.blob.TextBlob`* object. You just need to cast it to a string, or access its `.string` property:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd

def TBSpellCorrector(sentence):
    return TextBlob(sentence).correct().string # <<< See here

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':['on fre','beautful']})
df['sentence'].apply(TBSpellCorrector)
# 0       on are
# 1    beautiful
# Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

if the correct_sentence is in a list form, you can join them with `join`

```
>>> sent = ['o','n',' ','f','i','r','e']
>>> ''.join(sent)
'on fire'
```